# How to use python map function to generate the first 100 powers of two starting at 0 and exclusive of 100?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def map_twos():
    def pwr(x):
        return 2**x 
    map(pwr, range(0, 100))
    print pwr.get[2]
    return pwr
```

What is wrong. I don't know how do I use map function to get the required answer

Comment: Do you need specifically map?

Comment: yes. I need to solve this using map

Comment: read the documentation for map, it does not perform in-place, nor can it transform a function in something else.

Comment: @PauloBu 's answer was right on track, just needed math.pow: `l=map(lambda x: math.pow(x,2), xrange(0, 100))`

Comment: I don't know your exact situation, but if you don't need to use map you could do something like [i**2 for i in range(100)]

Comment: @Manuel You can calculate powers of 2 using bitwise left shifts, he just had the `1` and the `x` mixed up.

Comment: Please read http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map before asking this kind of question on SO. Minimal research effort is expected.

Comment: @Cu3PO42 when you say `x << 1` you are just shifting bits, thats multiplying by 2 not by x itself. ergo, you need pow.

Comment: @Manuel True `x << 1` is the same as multiplying by two, but `1 << x` is the same as `2^x`, subsequently you don't necessarily need pow or the `**` operator.

Comment: @Cu3PO42 Facepalm! I thought OP wanted `2**n` now I see is `n**2`, non native english speaker here, I have issues with some tech language sometimes.

Comment: @ManuelGutierrez the OP does want `2**n` and `1 << n` does exactly that...

Comment: @Cu3PO42 Don't you just hate a typo when trying to correct yourself? Thanks for the fix. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`pwr` is a function. Even after you map it over a list, `pwr` is still a function. `map(pwr, range(0, 100))` is the list you want. You can store it in a variable:

```
powers = map(pwr, range(0, 100))
print powers[2]
return powers
```

Comment: Note for Python3 users, `map` returns a map object, not a list, so subscripting here will not work. In your case, use `powers = list(map(pwr, range(0, 100)))`

Comment: @iCodez which is why I posted that as a comment directly explicitly at "Python3 users." It was never meant as a suggestion for OP

Answer (score 0):

`map` does not modify the existing list or function, but instead generates an *iterator* over the result (in Python 3). That means you need to store the result of `map` and eventually convert it to a `list` of you need to get the n-th element (in Python 3).

```
pwrs = map(lambda n: 1 << n, xrange(100))
print pwrs[2]
```

From the use of the print statement I figured you were using Python 2, so I left out the explicit conversion to a `list` and used `xrange` which returns an iterator (leading to better performance). In Python 3 `xrange` does not exist anymore however and `range` always returns an iterator. Also notice how I left out the lower boundary on the `range` function, because it defaults to 0. Instead of predefining a function I used a `lambda` here, which in turn uses a bitwise leftshift , because it is usually  faster than using the `**` (power) operator.