# Find the powers of 2 from 2^0 to 2^99 using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

```
def lst_comp():
    list = []
    list = (2**i for i in range(100))
    print list
    return list
```

I get this when I do this : `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000000034C48B8>`

Comment: Are you just asking us [all your homweork problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416953/how-to-use-python-map-function-to-generate-the-first-100-powers-of-two-starting#21417108)?

Comment: You should practice your reading skills, this question is answered in the comments of your other one.

Answer (score 8):

You created a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), **not** a list comprehension. Use `[...]` square brackets around the expression instead of `(...)` round parenthesis:

```
def lst_comp():
    lst = [2**i for i in range(100)]
    print lst
    return lst
```

A generator expression is very closely related to a list comprehension; it produces the exact same values, but lazily as you iterate over the object. A list comprehension produces all values in one go and returns a list object containing them.

You could also have done:

```
generator = (2**i for i in range(100))
lst = list(generator)
```

to consume the whole generator object in one go and produce a list object from the results.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem comes from the fact that you used a generator comprehension `(...)`, as opposed to a list comprehension `[...]`.

```
def lst_comp():
    myList = [2**i for i in range(100)]
    return myList
```

As a side note, it is a horrible idea to name your variables `list`, `file`, `dict`, etc, as they are types of data structures in python